# Linguagem para Backend e outra no Frontend?

Tags: python

Tenho um programa desktop sem GUI funcionando em Python, gostaria de adicionar uma GUI utilizando outra linguagem principalmente uma com algum editor visual ,C++ por exemplo, para ser um frontend, isso seria possível? O quão impactante seria no desempenho e na utilização? O que pensam sobre a ironpython?

Obs: Já testei o PAGE, mas não me senti satisfeito.

Comment: Isto parece fazer pouco sentido, já vi as pessoas fazerem o contrário.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, é possivel criar GUI sim. Eu recomendo utilizar o [Pyside](https://wiki.qt.io/PySide), ou o [pyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt). Pois tem uma IDE drag and drop de arrastar e soltar muito boa, e você pode "compilar" para executavel .exe Windows com o Pyinstaller. Nenhum impacto no desempenho.
Print Screen IDE drag and drop: https://screenshots.firefox.com/T2KK91KbDDQnOS4C/null

Comment: Qual seria essa IDE Drag and Drop?

Comment: Tem certeza que elas tem IDE Drag and Drop, não consegui instalar nenhuma das duas opções.... Enquanto ao tópico em si, para fazer o GUI eu recomendo o Kivy se for simples, use o tkinter, mas é tudo na base de código, infelizmente....

Comment: A IDE IDE Drag and Drop é o "Qt Designer" to usando, muito bom. Maneira fácil de instalar é usando o PySide se vc tiver usando Python 2.7 com o comando:
pip install PySide
 Ja se você estiver usando Python 3.6 pode usar o PySide2 ou o próprio Qt baixado no site www.qt.io. Pra programar para Windows e Linux eu acho mil vezes melhor que o Kivy.

Comment: Veja a imagem dessa IDE aqui no meu computador  https://screenshots.firefox.com/T2KK91KbDDQnOS4C/null

Comment: Eu vi esse QT, tentei baixar o download sempre da problema, vou tentar mais tarde

Comment: Eu criei um setup de instalação offline dele para o Windows, funciona para Python 2.7, mas para Python 3, só funciona até a versão 3.4 do Python. Eu uso Python 2.7 pois a maioria das coisas que eu utilizo é incompatível com Python 3. Aqui esta o link, basta baixar e executar como administrador, são apenas 30MB. 
Link: https://www.4shared.com/file/95UHcGj9gm/PySide_Setup.html

Comment: po, ai python 2.7 você quebra as pernas kkkkkk

Comment: Para Python 3.6 você terá que baixar do próprio www.qt.io mas ai o download é mais de 1GB, ou baixar o PySide2.